# lxml - unable to replace children of children

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, lxml, lxml.objectify

I'm using lxml as a solution for XML parsing in my application.

I understand that lxml can only replace the immediate child of a parent, but no levels under that child using [.replace](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html)

Example XML:

```
<root>

    <dc>

        <batman alias='dark_knight' />

    </dc>

</root>
```

I have a modified tag in a string like so

```
<batman alias='not_dark_knight' />
```

I need some help with replacing the original XML using xpath '/root/dc/batman'.

```
from lxml import etree

original_xml = "<root><dc><batman alias='dark_knight' /></dc></root>"
modified_tag = "<batman alias='not_dark_knight' />"
x_path = '/root/dc/batman'
original_obj = etree.fromstring(original_xml)
modified_obj = etree.fromstring(modified_tag)

original_obj.replace(original_obj.xpath(x_path)[0], modified_obj)
```

This throws a **ValueError:  Element is not a child of this node.**
Is there a way i can replace the string nicely?  (only using lxml)

Please understand that I would like a solution using lxml library only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know, you should be calling `replace()` on the *parent of the element you want to replace*. You may use `.getparent()` to dynamically get to the parent:

```
batman = original_obj.xpath(x_path)[0]
batman.getparent().replace(batman, modified_obj)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you @alecxe. I might have missed that. :)